# Sending a request to the Nagios service to be monitored

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nagios

What I know is `Nagios` is a tool used to monitor remote servers by configuring it.

But I have a requirement in which I need other remote server applications to be sending a request to the `Nagios` service at particular intervals and saying that I'm running and this is my status. Googling it didn't give any information so far. So I just want to know if this is possible with `Nagios`.

Can you please help me with this query so that I can fulfill my requirement.

If not `Nagios`, is there any other application capable of doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

You need NSClient++ running on your Windows machine and NSCA running on your Nagios server, have a look for install guides. It's not the easiest thing to get working.